# Why does VS Code debugger not open library modules when I press F11 (step into)?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In trying to solve some errors I am having I would like VS Code debugger to hold my hand and take from module to module, line by line so I can see how the code works. This works as expected if I create two .py files and have code from one call a function from the other.

So if I have one file have the code:

```
def printer(text):
    print(text)
```

and the second one just say:

```
from first_file import printer
printer('Hello')
```

when I put a break point on line `printer('Hello')` of the second file then, when the code stops there, I press F11, it will open the 1st file and I can continue pressing F11 to go on line by line.

This does not seem to happen with my current code which uses a parameter tuner from scikit-learn, namely GridSearchCV. If I put a break point on the line of code which calls the `.fit` method for this tuner, when the code pauses there and I press F11 it will just carry on and not walk me through the scikit-learn jungle.

Is there a way to make this happen? Some obscure setting that my googling has not revealed?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to add `"justMyCode": false` in the `launch.json` file? like this:

[image]

Otherwise, the debugger will only walk through the codes written by the user.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Steven. I have tried and this has not worked unfortunately.